# Deep comparison and getting values in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, underscore.js

I do not have time to create a fiddle right now, but will definetely do so tomorrow.
Basically my problem is caching a data model retrieved from a restful get endpoint and comparing to a new model returned by a restful updated endpoint in order to be able to highlight the changed values in the UI.
The way I handled this is by using underscore's each() and angular.compare() methods in order to loop through a collection and compare it object key by object key.
However this feels wrong and I have problems in getting the updated key name.
Is there a better, accepted way to do this as I cannot find anything anywhere, just a bunch of people generally asking the same question and getting answers like: 'Use a watcher and underscore/angular methods, it is easy'.

Comment: a streamlined data sample would really help as well as posting your filtering code

Comment: If you do not even have time to give an example, you shouldn't expect us to have time to give an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For what I have understand, what you are trying to do is the correct way to see it.
You have to compare object by object.
To help you between the old collection and the new one, a watcher is not a bad answer. In fact the angular watcher can give you the old collection and the new one as parameters. So all you got to do is make a check object by object. And had a special treamenton the different values.
Hope this can help you.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, the question was asked when I was not that familiar with ng and lots of things did not really made sense. I found a solution then, very close to what you described.